Bunit.Extensions.WaitForHelpers.WaitForFailedException after running all tests
With Bunit, my test always pass if I run I lonely. In the contrary, if I run all my 284 tests, I get this error like half the time and I do not know why. This is really frustrating because this is unstable tests.
using Bunit;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Components.Pages.Games;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Data.Services.Interfaces;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Exceptions;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Helper.Interfaces;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Models;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Models.Childs;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Models.Criterias;
using LesLumieres.Serveur.Models.Lists;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using Moq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Security.Claims;
using TestContext = Bunit.TestContext;


namespace LesLumieres.Tests.Components.Pages.Games
{
    public class ManageGameTest
    {
        private TestContext _testContext;
        private Mock<IGameService> _gameService;
        private Mock<IParcoursService> _parcoursService;
        private Mock<ILogger<ManageGame>> _logger;
        private Mock<IJSRuntime> _js;
        private Mock<INavigationService> _navigationService;
        private Mock<AuthenticationStateProvider> _authStateProv;
        private int _gameId = 23;
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _testContext = new TestContext(); 

        _gameService = new Mock<IGameService>();
        _parcoursService = new Mock<IParcoursService>();
        _logger = new Mock<ILogger<ManageGame>>();
        _js = new Mock<IJSRuntime>();
        _navigationService = new Mock<INavigationService>();
        _authStateProv = new Mock<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
        var fakeUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test User"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "testuser@example.com")
        }, "mock"));

        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(fakeUser));
        _authStateProv.Setup(a => a.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).Returns(authState);


        _testContext.Services.AddSingleton<IGameService>(_gameService.Object);
        _testContext.Services.AddSingleton<IParcoursService>(_parcoursService.Object);
        _testContext.Services.AddSingleton<ILogger<ManageGame>>(_logger.Object);
        _testContext.Services.AddSingleton<IJSRuntime>(_js.Object);
        _testContext.Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService>(_navigationService.Object); 
        _testContext.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider>(_authStateProv.Object);

        _parcoursService
            .Setup(ps => ps.GetAll(It.IsAny<ParcoursCriterias>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new ParcoursDtoList()
            {
                ListParcours = new List<ParcoursDto>()
                {
                    new ParcoursDto()
                    {
                        Id= 23,
                        Name = "NAME_SUGGESTED_1",
                        Questions = new List<QuestionDto>()
                        {
                            new ChoiceOfAnswerDto(),
                            new ChoiceOfAnswerDto()
                        }
                    },
                    new ParcoursDto()
                    {
                        Id= 99,
                        Name = "NAME_PARCOURS",
                        Questions = new List<QuestionDto>()
                        {
                            new ChoiceOfAnswerDto(),
                            new ChoiceOfAnswerDto()
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        _gameService
            .Setup(gs => gs.GetAsync(23))
            .ReturnsAsync(
                new GameDto()
                {
                    Id= 23,
                    Name = "GAME_NAME",
                    GameParcours = new List<GameParcoursDto>()
                    {
                        new GameParcoursDto()
                        {
                            Parcours = new ParcoursDto()
                            {
                                Id = 99,
                                Name = "NAME_PARCOURS"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Players = new List<PlayerDto>()
                    {
                        new PlayerDto()
                        {
                            Name = "PLAYER_1_NOT_MODIFIED",
                            EmojiIcon = "",
                            NoOrdre = 1
                        },
                        new PlayerDto()
                        {
                            Name = "PLAYER_2_NOT_MODIFIED",
                            EmojiIcon = "",
                            NoOrdre = 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _testContext.DisposeComponents();
        _testContext.Dispose();
    }
    [Test]
    public void GivenGame_WhenSaveModifedGame_ThenGameIsSaved()
    {
        // Arrange
        var cut = _testContext.RenderComponent<ManageGame>(args =>
            args
                .Add(arg => arg.Id, _gameId)
        );

        var gameName = "NAME_OF_THE_GAME";
        var inputName = cut.Find("#name");
        cut.WaitForState(() => cut.Find("#name") != null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        cut.Find("#name").Change(new ChangeEventArgs
        {
            Value = gameName
        });

        // Act
        cut.WaitForState(() => cut.Find("#save-game") != null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        var saveGame = cut.Find("#save-game");
        saveGame.Click();
        cut.WaitForState(() => cut.Instance.Game.Name == gameName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        cut.WaitForState(() => cut.Markup.Contains("La partie a bien été modifiée."), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

        // Assert
        Assert.That(cut.Markup.Contains("La partie a bien été modifiée."), Is.True);
        _gameService.Verify(gs => gs.Modify(It.Is<GameDto>(dto =>
            dto.Name == gameName)), Times.Once);
    }

This is my tested page:
@page "/GererPartie/{Id:int}"

@attribute [Authorize()]

@inject IGameService GameService
@inject ILogger<ManageGame> Logger
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject INavigationService NavigationService

@attribute [Authorize()]

<Notification Message="@Message" Success="@Success" OnClear="HandleClearNotification" />
<ParcoursModal Game="@Game" Save="AddParcours" GameParcours="@GameParcours" />
<PlayerModal Game="@Game" Player="@PlayerSelected" Save="AddPlayer" />
<div class="container">
    <h3>@Action une partie</h3>

<EditForm Model="@Game" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Nom</label>
                <InputText id="name" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Game.Name" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Game.Name)" />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Joueurs</label>
                    <button id="add-player" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ms-3" @onclick="() => OpenModalPlayers(null)">Ajouter</button>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ajouté</th>
                            <th>Ordre de jeu</th>
                            <th>Icône</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var player in Game.Players.OrderBy(p => p.NoOrdre))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @if (PlayersLoading.Any(pId => pId == player.Name))
                                    {
                                        <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" role="status">
                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" style="color:green;font-size:2rem;"></i>
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <b>#@player.NoOrdre</b>
                                    @if (player.NoOrdre != 1)
                                    {
                                        <button id="up-player" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-1" @onclick="() => UpPlayer(player)">
                                            <i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    }
                                    @if (player.NoOrdre != Game.Players.Count)
                                    {
                                        <button id="down-player" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-1" @onclick="() => DownPlayer(player)">
                                            <i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="mx-1 align-self-center">@player.EmojiIcon</div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="mx-1 align-self-center"><b>@player.Name</b></div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="() => OpenModalPlayers(player)">Modifier</button>
                                    <button id="remove-player" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="() => RemovePlayer(player)">Supprimer</button>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Parcours</label>
                    <button id="add-parcours" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ms-3" @onclick="() => OpenModalParcours()">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ajouté</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var gameParcours in Game.GameParcours)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @if (ParcoursLoading.Any(pId => pId == gameParcours.ParcoursId))
                                    {
                                        <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" role="status">
                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill" style="color:green;font-size:2rem;"></i>
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="mx-1 align-self-center">@gameParcours.Parcours.Name</div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <button id="remove-parcours" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="() => DeleteParcoursFromGame(gameParcours.ParcoursId)">Supprimer</button>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="text-start">
                <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" @onclick="() => NavigationService.RedirectToGames()">
                    <i class="bi bi-arrow-90deg-left"></i> Retour
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-game">
                    @if (IsLoading)
                    {
                        <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="ms-2">Chargement...</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Action
                    }
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    bool Success;
    public GameDto Game { get; set; } = new GameDto()
        {
            Id = 0,
            Players = new List<PlayerDto>(),
            GameParcours = new List<GameParcoursDto>(),
            Name = string.Empty
        };
    public string Action { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private bool IsLoading;
    string Message;
    private List<ParcoursDto> ParcoursSelected = new();
    private List<int> ParcoursLoading { get; set; } = new();
    private List<string> PlayersLoading { get; set; } = new();
    private PlayerDto PlayerSelected { get; set; } = new();
    private List<PlayerDto> PlayersSelected = new();
    public List<GameParcoursDto> GameParcours { get; set; } = new();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        if (Id != 0)
        {
            Game = await GameService.GetAsync(Id);
            if (Game == null)
            {
                await Creating();
            }
            else
            {
                Action = "Modifier";
                ParcoursSelected = Game.GameParcours.Select(gp => gp.Parcours).ToList();
                PlayersSelected = Game.Players.ToList();
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Creating();
        }
        SetGameParcours();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is NotAuthorizeException || ex is NotConnectedException)
    {
        Message = ex.Message;
        Success = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        Message = "Une erreur inattendue s'est produite.";
        Success = false;
    }
}

My goal is to have stable test and I do not know why this test fail a lot when I run all my test. Sometimes it pass. I wonder if I do not miss something with bunit or anything else. Let me know.

What's the error you have get? Please share the details error message to let us check about it.
